# Why does java stream.count() return a long?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why doesn't a [`stream.count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--) return an `int`?

I understand that I can easily convert the `long` to an `int` by casting,

```
return (int) players.stream().filter(Player::isActive).count();
```

but **why** would a java `stream.count()` return a `long` instead of an `int`?

Comment: Why should it return an int if you can easily convert from a small-enough long to int, but not from an overflown int back to long?

Comment: When you dealing with stream, normally it would be something that very very big hence the reason for streaming. Converting long into an int will lose percision if the number is big.

Comment: because `long` is longer than `int`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well simply because it's the biggest 64-bit primitive value that java has.
The other way would be *two* counts:

```
countLong/countInt
```

and that would look really weird.

`int` fits in a `long`, but not the other way around. Anything you want to do with int you can fit in a long, so why the need to provide both?

Comment: What if I want to save memory ? Ex. Count the number of characters in a long string, knowing that each character will never occur more than Integer.MAX. It would be a waste of memory to use Long instead of Integer in this case.

Answer (score 23):

When Java came out in early 1996, common PCs had 8 to 16 Mb of memory. Since both arrays and collections were closely tied to memory size, using `int` to represent element counts seemed natural, because it was sufficient to address an array of `int`s that is 4Gb in size - a size gigantic even for hard drives in 1996, let alone RAM. Hence, using `long` instead of `int` for collection sizes would seem wasteful at the time.

Although `int` size may be a limiting factor at times, Java designers cannot change it to `long`, because it would be a breaking change.

Unlike Java collections, streams could have potentially unlimited number of elements, and they carry no compatibility considerations. Therefore, using `long` with its wider range of values seems like a very reasonable choice.

Comment: Some Java collections can also contain a potentially unlimited number of elements (like LinkedList) even though their `size` will be reported wrong.

Answer (score 23):

This statement

```
players.stream().filter(Player::isActive).count();
```

is equivalent to:

```
players.stream().filter(Player::isActive).collect(Collectors.counting());
```

This still returns a `long` because `Collectors.counting()` is implemented as

```
reducing(0L, e -> 1L, Long::sum)
```

Returning an `int` can be accomplished with the following:

```
players.stream().filter(Player::isActive).collect(Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

This form can be used in `groupingBy` statement

```
Map<Player, Integer> playerCount = players.stream().filter(Player::isActive).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
```

Comment: I see a problem when I use .count(); instead of .collect(Collectors.counting());. It does a simple count without processing business logic